# Parsing NSBlockOperation's executionBlocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView where each section contains a single row which each contain a UICollectionView.  The UITableView is the data source and delegate to a Core Data database.  Updates to the database call the NSFetchedResultsController's controller: didChangeObject: method which queues blocks to update the relevant collection as so:

```
switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
        [self.blockOperation addExecutionBlock:^{
            [collectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.section] ];
        }];
    break;
}...
```

I then want to execute the blocks here as a batch:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.blockOperation start];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Do whatever
    }];
}
```

This is using Ash Furrow's and Blake Watters' [techniques](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController/issues/13) for hooking up a core data database to a UICollectionView.

My question is, how do I get access to the correct collectionView object in `-controllerdidChangeContent:`?  Each block within self.blockOperation has the relevant collectionView, but I don't know how to parse it out from the NSBlockOperation's executionBlocks property, or even if that's the best way to get at it.  Ash and Blake's example only has one UICollectionView whereas I have many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use only a single block operation because you won't be able to separate the data afterwards. Instead, use one block operation per collection view (which is also per section). Add each to a dictionary with the associated index path as the key (check it one already exists and create / update as necessary). When you run the blocks, iterate the dictionary, get the collection view for the index path (key) and run the block operation (value).